# A triple sum related question

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation

I'm trying to compute the triple sum

```
Sum[ 1/(i! j! k! ), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, i + 1, Infinity}, {k, j + 1, Infinity}]
```

but *Mathematica*  doesn't return any value.

What else can I do here? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because it does not have an exact values in terms of $\pi$, $e$ and other known constants or functions. `N[Sum[1/(i! j! k!), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, i + 1, Infinity}, {k, j + 1,
    Infinity}]]` computes fine and returns `0.122759`.

Comment: Maybe `NSum` is sufficient in your case ?

Comment: @m0nhawk: I'm sure that in the answer must also be the constant $e$. The triple sums also involves the hypergeometric function but this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: @Chris'ssister: 1. It was just an assumption why it does not compute nothing. 2. That a function that gives the numerical value of expression, see [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html).

Comment: @m0nhawk: thank you very much for the explanations offered!

Comment: @m0nhawk: One more question: how may I get more decimals here?

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Just `N[<expression>, <number of digits>]`. And, are you sure summation over `j` and `k` is done from `i + 1` and `j + 1`? This sum: `Sum[1/(i! j! k!), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, Infinity}, {k, 1, Infinity}]` equals to `(e - 1)^3`.

Comment: @m0nhawk: the way I wrote the initial sum is correct since the second sum you suggested may be computed mentally :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One can get an explicit result using symmetric functions.  First rewrite the infinite sum as a finite sum:

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}{1\over{i!j!k!}}$$

Now define the power sums:

$$s_j=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k!)^{-j}$$

We can now rewrite $S_n$ as a function of $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$:

$$S_n=(2 s_3 - 3 s_2 s_1 + s_1^3)/6$$

The limit can now be found by finding the limits of the power sums and then plugging in those limits to the previous equation:

```
s1Limit = Sum[1/i!, {i, 1, ∞}]
(* -1 + e *)
s2Limit = Sum[1/(i!)^2, {i, 1, ∞}]
(* -1  +BesselI[0,2] *)
s3Limit = Sum[1/(i!)^3, {i, 1, ∞}]
(* -1 + HypergeometricPFQ[{},{1,1},1] *)
sLimit = (2 s3Limit - 3 s2Limit s1Limit + s1Limit^3)/6
```

[image: Result]

A numeric approximation is

```
N[sLimit]
(* 0.12275911513957549 *)
```